Mutliple series inductors instead of single inductor
For the larger package size and slightly better SRF and Q I would prefer to use 3 series SMD inductors instead of the only 270 nH SMD I can find with the required Q. Also I would avoid winding my own coils.
Making myself an FM notch filter: https://www.sdrplay.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4317&sid=075461ec1cf8a599c0cd76b15c681002
Are there any catches when going like this, 3 series inductors instead of one ?

Your parasitics (both series L and shunt C) will be subtly different building an inductor this way. You may need to tune your filter more than you expect to reproduce the curves shown in the original article.
Do arrange to have some tuning range available. A surface-mount method of tuning inductors is to have a pair of parallel lines that you can bridge in varying positions with a short. Less tidy, but easier to adjust, is a few turn coil off the board that you can change the shape of with pliers.

Where can I read more on that pair of parallel lines for a variabe inductor ?

@kellogs I can't find anything written on it. As you're making an adjustable inductor, calculating an exact value doesn't matter too much, all you need is a ballpark for the range. And, the ballpark is, 1 nH per mm. This is true enough for thin wires, and traces on a board, in single turn loops of practical sizes. Here are the parallel wires, say a few mm apart ======|=== with a link soldered across them part the way along. Move the position of the short, and the inductance from one end changes by a few nH.
